# render to FrameBuffer not working in combination with ShapeRenderer in a custom Actor (libgdx)

Tags: libgdx, actor, framebuffer

I try to implement a custom Actor which displays contents of a FrameBuffer by extending Image. Inside I'd like to draw using a ShapeRenderer.

```
public class CustomActor extends Image {
    private FrameBuffer frameBuffer = null;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public CustomActor() {
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (frameBuffer == null) {
            frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width / 2, height / 2, false);
            TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
            textureRegion.flip(false, true);

            setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(textureRegion));
        }

        frameBuffer.begin();

        // render content
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, frameBuffer.getWidth() / 2, frameBuffer.getHeight() / 2);
        shapeRenderer.end();

        if (frameBuffer != null) {
            frameBuffer.end();
        }

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }
}
```

When deleting the ShapeRenderer part I can see the green background in the scene. But as soon as I use the ShapeRenderer the content is black. There is no white rectangle visible.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Create the framebuffer inside of the Constructor and not inside of the draw. You only do it once so it does not need to be checked 60 times a second. Always call the `framebuffer.end()` if you call the `framebuffer.begin()`. Check the width and height values if they are not 0.

Comment: Yes, there are some design weaknesses. Thanks for improvement advice. The sizes seem to be ok (debugging tells me that the sizes are not 0) and, as mentioned above, without the ShapeRenderer code the green rectangle is drawn (Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);).

Comment: Just found out that using my own SpriteBatch (with begin() and end()) after the FrameBuffer end() it works. So the problem seems to have to do with the calling order of the FrameBuffers methods and the SpriteBatches methods. 
Ending the given actor batch before beginning the FrameBuffer and "re"-beginning it to draw the actor is also working.
But I still don't know why mixing these calls is not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that using my own SpriteBatch (with begin() and end()) after the FrameBuffer end() it works. So the problem seems to have to do with the calling order of the FrameBuffers methods and the SpriteBatches methods. Ending the given actor batch before beginning the FrameBuffer and "re"-beginning it to draw the actor is also working (see comment above).